# Add in a list from an API Rest in jetpack Compose

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit

Functionality: This is a card game in which each player has a series of cards that are superheroes that I take from a superhero API, all with powestates, these abilities define the power of the card that will make the players fight one against the other to see who is the best.

Using coroutines I have an API of superheroes and this line is where the crash is found:

```
fun getSuperHeroe(){
        //iniciamos una corrutina
        var lista:MutableList<SuperHero> ?= null
        viewModelScope.launch {
                try {
                    val numAleatorio = Random.nextInt(1, 732).toString()
                    val superHeroId = SuperHeroApi.retrofitService.getSuperHeroById(numAleatorio)
                    val gson = Gson()
                    var superheroResponse = gson.fromJson(superHeroId, SuperHero::class.java)
                    superHero = superheroResponse
                    lista!!.add(superHero)
                    _superHeroDeck.value = lista
                }catch (e:IOException){

                }
        }
    }
```

If I only have the superHeroes is everything good but if I have to add to the list the superheroe is where everything start to crash, this is the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                    Process: com.example.applibre, PID: 19160                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                        at com.example.applibre.ui.model.HeroDeckViewModel$getSuperHeroe$1.invokeSuspend(HeroDeckViewModel.kt:71)                                                                                                       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)                                                                                                       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@74f01f0, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
2024-02-14 00:56:17.119 19160-19160 Process                 com.example.applibre                 I  Sending signal. PID: 19160 SIG: 9
```

I have the data class perfectly created. I try to put a list inside the code but is impossible, This is more or less what I want:

```
suspend fun getSuperHeroeById(id:String){
        //iniciamos una corrutina
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val superHeroId = SuperHeroApi.retrofitService.getSuperHeroById(id)
                val gson = Gson()
                var superheroResponse = gson.fromJson(superHeroId, SuperHeroe::class.java)
                character = superheroResponse
            }catch (e:IOException){

            }
        }
    }

    fun crearCartas(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val numAleatorio = Random.nextInt(1, 732).toString()
                var superHeroe = getSuperHeroeById(numAleatorio)
                val numAleatorio2 = Random.nextInt(1, 732).toString()
                var superHeroe2 = getSuperHeroeById(numAleatorio2)
                var superHeroes:MutableList<SuperHeroe> = mutableListOf()
            }catch (e:IOException){

            }
        }
    }
```

Explained: is putting a list of superheroes (card) for each player.

This is the actual code of the `viewModel`:

```
class HeroDeckViewModel:ViewModel(){
    private val _player = MutableLiveData<Player>()

    private val _nickNamePlayer = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val nickNamePlayer1: LiveData<String> = _nickNamePlayer

    private val _characterDeck  = MutableStateFlow<List<SuperHeroe>>(emptyList())
    val characterDeck: StateFlow<List<SuperHeroe>> = _characterDeck

    var character by mutableStateOf(
        SuperHeroe(
            response = "",
            id = 0,
            name = "",
            powerStats = PowerStats(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            biography = Biography("", "", listOf(), "", "", "", ""),
            appearance = Appearance("", "", listOf(), listOf(), "", ""),
            work = Work("", ""),
            connections = Connections("", ""),
            image = Image("")
        )
    )
    private set;


    init {
        getSuperHeroe()
    }

    fun onPlayer(nickName:String){
        _nickNamePlayer.value = nickName
    }


    fun getSuperHeroe(){
        //iniciamos una corrutina
        viewModelScope.launch {
                try {
                    val numAleatorio = Random.nextInt(1, 732).toString()
                    val superHeroId = SuperHeroApi.retrofitService.getSuperHeroById(numAleatorio)
                    val gson = Gson()
                    var superheroResponse = gson.fromJson(superHeroId, SuperHeroe::class.java)
                    character = superheroResponse
                }catch (e:IOException){

                }
        }
    }

    /**
     * calcula el poder de los personajes
     */
    private fun checkPuntos(){
        val powerStats = character.powerStats
        val totalPowers = powerStats.power + powerStats.combat + powerStats.durability + powerStats.speed
        + powerStats.strength + powerStats.intelligence

        val powerPercentage = powerStats.power.toDouble() / totalPowers * 10
        val combatPercentage = powerStats.combat.toDouble() / totalPowers * 15
        val durabilityPercentage = powerStats.durability.toDouble() / totalPowers * 15
        val speedPercentage = powerStats.speed.toDouble() / totalPowers * 15
        val strengthPercentage = powerStats.strength.toDouble() / totalPowers * 20
        val intelligencePercentage = powerStats.intelligence.toDouble() / totalPowers * 25

        /*
        * cada turno da mana
        * y empiezas con uno de mana
        * cada carta tiene su propio coste de mana
        * */


    }

}
```

and this is the data classes:

```
data class Appearance(
    val gender: String,
    val race: String,
    val height: List<String>,
    val weight: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("eye-color")
    val eyeColor: String,
    @SerializedName("hair-color")
    val hairColor: String
)
```

```
data class Biography(
    @SerializedName("full-name")
    val fullName: String,
    @SerializedName("alter-egos")
    val alterEgos: String,
    val aliases: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("place-of-birth")
    val placeOfBirth: String,
    @SerializedName("first-appearance")
    val firstAppearance: String,
    val publisher: String,
    val alignment: String
)
```

```
data class Connections(
    @SerializedName("group-affilation")
    val groupAffiliation: String,
    val relatives: String
)
```

```
class Deck {

    companion object {
        // The list to store the deck of cards
        val listaCharacters: ArrayList<SuperHeroe> = ArrayList()

        /**
         * Genera un número aleatorio en el rango de 1 a 731
         * que son todos los posibles id
         */
        fun obtenerNumeroAleatorio(): Int {
            return Random.nextInt(1, 732)
        }

        fun shuffle() {
            listaCharacters.shuffle()
        }

        /**
         * Gets the last card from the deck.
         *
         * @return The last card in the deck.
         */
        fun getSuperHero(): SuperHeroe {
            val carta = listaCharacters.last()
            listaCharacters.removeLast()
            return carta
        }

        /**
         * Gets the total number of cards in the deck.
         *
         * @return The total number of cards in the deck.
         */
        fun getCardsTotal(): Int {
            return listaCharacters.size
        }

    }
}
```

```
datadata class Image(val url:String)
```

```
data class Player(
    var vida:Int,
    var nikeName:String,
    var characters:MutableList<SuperHeroe>
)
```

```
data class PowerStats(
    val intelligence: Int,
    val strength: Int,
    val speed: Int,
    val durability: Int,
    val power: Int,
    val combat: Int
)
```

```
data class SuperHeroe (
    val response:String,
    val id:Int,
    val name:String,
    @SerializedName("powerstats")
    val powerStats:PowerStats,
    val biography:Biography,
    val appearance:Appearance,
    val work:Work,
    val connections: Connections,
    val image:Image,
)
```

```
data class Work(
    val occupation: String,
    @SerializedName("base")
    val baseOfOperation: String
)
```

```
object SuperHeroApi {

   val retrofitService:SuperHeroApiService by lazy {
       retrofit.create(SuperHeroApiService::class.java)
   }
}
```

```
const val BASE_URL =
    "https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/934555588123234/"


val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()


interface SuperHeroApiService{

    /**
     * Obtiene todo del personaje
     */
    @GET("{id}")
    suspend fun getSuperHeroById(@Path("id") id: String): String


    /**
     * @return devuelve el id del personaje
     */
    @GET("search/{name}")
    suspend fun getSuperHeroByName(@Path("name") name: String): String
}
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun visualizar(){
    screen()
}
/*Contiene toda la pantalla*/
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun screen(){
    val heroDeckViewModel:HeroDeckViewModel = HeroDeckViewModel()
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                ),
                title = {
                    Text("Hero-Deck")
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            ) {
                Button(onClick = { heroDeckViewModel.getSuperHeroe() }) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        text = "Bottom app bar",
                    )
                }
            }
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        ) {
            LazyColumn{
                item { SuperHeroCard(character = heroDeckViewModel.character) }
            }

        }
    }
}

/**
 * imprime la carta
 */
@Composable
fun SuperHeroCard(character: SuperHeroe){
    var showText by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val urlImagen = character.image.url
    AsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(context = LocalContext.current)
            .data(urlImagen)
            .build(),
        contentDescription = "SuperHero",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )

    Button(onClick = { showText = !showText }, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 150.dp)) {
        Text(if (showText) "Ocultar" else "Ver más")
    }

    if (showText) {
        mostrar(character)
    }
}

@Composable
fun mostrar(character: SuperHeroe){
    Text(text = character.name)
    Text(text = character.powerStats.toString())
}
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppLibreTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    screen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is all the code and the API is this one: https://www.superheroapi.com/

Also you have the link to the app if you want to download the code better: https://github.com/jorgitorr/HeroDeck

I am expecting to have different superheroes inside the list of each player like this: (But working)

```
fun getSuperHeroe(){
        //iniciamos una corrutina
        var lista:MutableList<SuperHero> ?= null
        viewModelScope.launch {
                try {
                    val numAleatorio = Random.nextInt(1, 732).toString()
                    val superHeroId = SuperHeroApi.retrofitService.getSuperHeroById(numAleatorio)
                    val gson = Gson()
                    var superheroResponse = gson.fromJson(superHeroId, SuperHero::class.java)
                    superHero = superheroResponse
                    lista!!.add(superHero)
                    _superHeroDeck.value = lista
                }catch (e:IOException){

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: too much code, just change the line :        var lista:MutableList<SuperHero> ?= null
to val lista: MutableList<SuperHero> = mutableListOf()

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You declare your `lista` List like this:

```
var lista:MutableList<SuperHero> ?= null
```

And then, you next access it like this:

```
lista!!.add(superHero)
```

You are using `!!` which is the [not-null assertion operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator). It tries to convert a nullable type `MutableList<SuperHero>?` to a non-nullable type `MutableList<SuperHero>`. If `lista` is null, it will throw a `NullPointerException`, which is exactly what is happening in your case. You should only use `!!` if you are sure yourself that a value is **not** going to be `null`.

Instead of initializing `alist` to `null`, initialize it to an empty list:

```
val lista: MutableList<SuperHero> = mutableListOf()
```

Comment: thank you for that answer, but the question is not only that, is how can i get multiples superheroes without pushing the button, like with a loop inside the corrutine (But if i put a loop it will crash)

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code. But in general, a loop should work.

Comment: no, my code doesn´t have any loop because i prove it and it doesn´t work.